# how convert numbers to text in python

Tags: algorithm, encoding

I am new to Python and writing scripts/programs.

I want to convert numbers to text.
The problem is that the numbers are not separated by anything.

`11349` --> `TEI`

`16342734410` --> `FEUERS`

What number has to be which letter is already defined:

**A=6** B=12 C=15 D=5 E=34 **F=16** G=8 H=23 I=9 J=20 K=33 L=22 M=17 N=28 O=19 P=30 Q=7 R=4 S=10 T=11 U=27 V=13 W=31 X=14 Y=29 Z=35 ß=18 Ö=32 Ü=24 Ä=25

The bold parts are problematic since the 16 could be read as 1 and 6.

Numbers 1,2 and 3 are not defined in my list and have to be read together with the next single number.

Now I need a simple way to get python to do this.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Before you consider the programming barrier, you really have to solve the ambiguity issue....16 as '16' or 1,6 is not something any python program could just *know*.

Comment: You don't have a Python problem; you have an algorithms problem.

Comment: I know that the way i have to convert the numbers is idiotic.
Also the "translation table" is not my work.
I cannot change it... :/

Comment: Without seeing the full mapping, or at least knowing what assumptions are being made, there's no way we can know how to correctly decode your integers into characters. Does `3` map to something? Does `1`? Or do none of the single-digit codes appear at the start of any multi-digit code?

Comment: It may not be an algorithm problem - the international dialling codes for instance are done in such a way that it's possible to identify the m without them being fixed length... (but yes, it would require the entire translation to be able to check that)

Comment: Ok thanks.
Here is the full list:

A 6
B 12
C 15
D 5
E 34
F 16
G 8
H 23
I 9
J 20
K 33
L 22
M 17
N 28
O 19
P 30
Q 7
R 4
S 10
T 11
U 27
V 13
W 31
X 14
Y 29
Z 35
ß 18
Ö 32
Ü 24
Ä 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert your key to text only, so that `16` becomes `'16'`
2. Store this is in a map mapping "number" to code letter.
3. It looks like a greedy algorithm is desired. You need to look at the maximum length of a code "number", and examine a moving window of that length; if that doesn't match anything, then search for one smaller in your list, and so on until you have a miss. When you have a hit, output the letter found, and advance to a new window starting right after the matched text (numbers).

---

```
tablestr = '''A=6 B=12 C=15 D=5 E=34 F=16 G=8 H=23 I=9 J=20 K=33 L=22 M=17 N=28 O=19 P=30 Q=7 R=4 S=10 T=11 U=27 V=13 W=31 X=14 Y=29 Z=35 ß=18 Ö=32 Ü=24 Ä=25'''
translationtable = dict((k,v) for v,k in (pair.split('=') for pair in tablestr.split(' ')))
windowlen=2
def decodergen(codetext):
    windowstart = 0
    windowend = windowlen
    # stop when we get to the end of the input
    while windowend <= len(codetext):
       #reduce window until len 1 
       while windowend - windowstart >= 1:
          key = codetext[windowstart:windowend]
          #print key
          if key in translationtable:
             #setup new window
             windowstart = windowend
             windowend = windowstart + windowlen 
             yield translationtable[key]
             break # out of inner loop
          else:
             windowend -=1     
       if windowend - windowstart <= 0:
          raise ValueError('Could not locate translation for code input')

''.join(decodergen('16342734410')) #=> 'FEUERS'
```

---

Here's a much shorter implementation:

```
import re
rx = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(translationtable, key=len, reverse=True)))
print rx.sub(lambda m: translationtable[m.group()], '16342734410')
```

This relies on sorting by length of the key to privilege longer matches.

Comment: Wow, that's quite some code - why not (using your `translationtable`) use something like: `import re; rx = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(translationtable, key=len, reverse=True))); print rx.sub(lambda m: translationtable[m.group()], '16342734410')` ?

Comment: @JonClements Well, that's a good idea too, but this implements the algorithm "long hand", which I think might be good for OP to understand.

Answer (score -1):

First of all make a dictionary:

```
d = { '6' : "A",
      # etc
    }
```

Convert number to string:

```
code = str(my_num)
```

Then parse it like this:

```
t = ""
res = ""
for i in code:
    t += i
    if t in d.keys():
        res += d[t]
        t = ""
```

Variable `res` will keep the result.